# Is wavelength expressed in astronomical unit?

Tags: x-rays, x-ray-crystallography

i have a question!

is wavelength expressed in astronomical unit?

I know that it is possible to express it, but is it done in books or questions?

Comment: Do you mean Angstroms? Otherwise unclear.

Comment: Whose wavelength? can you change units? Show your work.

Comment: An astronomical unit of length is about 93 million miles. It would be inconvenient to write an x-ray wavelength (0.01 - 10 nm) in these units.

Comment: You can express a wavelength using any unit of length. I have never seen AU used for any kind of wave, and *certainly* not for x-rays.

Comment: "au" often means "arbitrary units". But that is usually on the y-axis (for intensity) as a function of wavelength.